# How do I pass an argument from Windows Batch to single Powershell Command?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch, environment-variables

I know I can pass variables to a powershell script like this: `powershell -file ".\filetorun.ps1" "arg1" "arg2"` and put `param(var1=args[0],var2=args[1])` in the Powershell script.

But how do I do this if it is an inline batch command as an example:

```
set "folder=d:\test"
powershell -command "(Get-ChildItem -Recurse "<pass %folder% variable???>" | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).sum"
```

And then preferably provide that powershell result as a variable back to the batch file?

Thanks.

EDIT:

So it seems you can't pass a variable back through a pipe in batch, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446972/why-doesnt-set-p-work-after-a-pipe

Basically need to pass it through a text document. The commands below seem to work, although not ideal, but I guess this is how batch likes to work:

```
set "folder=d:\test"
powershell -command "(Get-ChildItem -Recurse '%folder%' | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).sum">_tempfile.txt
set /p size=<_tempfile.txt
del /f /q _tempfile.txt
echo %size%
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the job.

```
@echo off
set "folder=d:\test"
powershell -command "(Get-ChildItem -Recurse '%folder%' | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).sum" | set /p size=
echo %size%
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Just passing `%folder%` argument seems to work, and I swear I tried that yesterday but it balked (I dunno was late and was tired), but thank you. However, it is not passing the variable back to the batch file. it just states "ECHO IS OFF" telling me that the variable `size` is not passed back. I found this interesting discussion, but it seems not as straight forward. You basically need to store it in a file and then read back the contents of that file to store in the batch variable. Why is batch so silly like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446972

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a fully functional demonstration, a Write-Output has been added to the PowerShell statement. This ensures that a message is written to the standard output when the command is called. The for loop is used to run the PowerShell command and retrieve the standard output. Essentially, I was looking for a way to capture the output of an executable file and store it in a batch variable, because in this case, the output is produced by powershell.exe.

```
@echo off
set "folder=C:\temp"

REM test output
powershell -command "Write-Output (Get-ChildItem -Recurse '%folder%' | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).sum"

REM using for to catch the output to a cmd variable
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`powershell -command "Write-Output (Get-ChildItem -Recurse '%folder%' | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).sum"`) DO (
SET var=%%F
)
ECHO %var%
pause
```